# Calculating limit using sub sequences $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }\frac{(-5)^{n}+2\cdot(-2)^{n}+3}{5^{n+1}+2\cdot(-3)^{n}+3}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the following limit if it exists , if it does not exist (even not infinity) explain if it does exist then also find all the Sub sequential limits. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }\frac{(-5)^{n}+2\cdot(-2)^{n}+3}{5^{n+1}+2\cdot(-3)^{n}+3}$

Before I show what I tried , Sorry if some words and terms are not translated right as I could not find the terms after searching , would appreciate if someone can help edit if there are mistakes.

My try:

First let $a_n=\frac{(-5)^{n}+2\cdot(-2)^{n}+3}{5^{n+1}+2\cdot(-3)^{n}+3}$ then I wrote it in a more "comfortable" way so $\frac{5^n\cdot(-1)^{-n}+(2)^{n+1} \cdot(-1)^{n}+3}{5^{n+1}+2\cdot(-3)^{n}+3}$ and then $\frac{(-1)^{n}\cdot(5^n+(2)^{n+1})+3}{5^{n+1}+2\cdot(-3)^{n}+3}$

if we look at the subsequences $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ then they  cover the sequence $(a_n)$
and if two sub sequences converge to the same limit and they cover the sequence $(a_n)$ then $(a_n)$ also converges.

1. $(a_{2n})$ = $\frac{(5^n+(2)^{2n+1})+3}{5^{2n+1}+2\cdot(3)^{2n}+3}$
   so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }\frac{(5^n+(2)^{2n+1})+3}{5^{2n+1}+2\cdot(3)^{2n}+3}$ and using basic arithmetic limit rules $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }\frac{5^{2n}}{5^{2n+1}}\cdot\frac{(1+\frac{2^{2n+1}}{5^{2n}}+\frac{3}{5^{2n}})}{(1+\frac{2\cdot(3)^{2n}}{5^{2n+1}}+\frac{3}{5^{2n+1}})}$ = $\frac{1}{5}$
2. $(a_{2n+1})$ = $\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}\cdot(5^{2n+1}+(2)^{2n+2})+3}{5^{2n+2}+2\cdot(-3)^{2n+1}+3}$ so we get  $(a_{2n+1})$ = $\frac{-5^{2n+1}-(2)^{2n+2}+3}{5^{2n+2}-2\cdot(3)^{2n+1}+3}$
   then to calculate the limit I also used basic arithmetic rules
   $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{-5^{2n+1}-(2)^{2n+2}+3}{5^{2n+2}-2\cdot(3)^{2n+1}+3}$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{5^{2n+1}}{5^{2n+2}}\cdot\frac{(-1-\frac{2^{2n+2}}{5^{2n+1}}+\frac{3}{5^{2n+1}})}{(1+\frac{2\cdot(3)^{2n+1}}{5^{2n+2}}+\frac{3}{5^{2n+2}})} = -\frac {1}{5}$

so I got that the limits of the subsequences are different , can I conclude from that that the limit of $(a_n)$ does not exist? is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: $(-5)^{-n}\neq 5^n \cdot (-1)^{-n}$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I just edited I noticed I had a typo thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a theorem that you may or may not have proved yet that goes something like the following:

If $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell$, then any subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ converges to $\ell$ as well.

So, if there are two subsequences that converge to two different values, that must mean that the original sequence does not converge.

Double check your class notes and the textbook to see if you've already proved this (or another similar theorem), but from there you've already done the work to prove that it does not converge.

Comment: thank you much appreciated , so I guess my way of solving turns out to be right somehow because of the theorem you noted?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: sorry for the questions but are the 2 limits that i found , are they all the Sub sequential limits?.

Comment: That I don't know.  You could check the absolute value sequence?  If that converges, then I think that would show that those are the only two limits...

You could also check different subsequences.  Does something change when you look at different remainders mod 4 (4n, 4n+1, 4n+2, 4n+3) or mod 6 or mod 8 (instead of mod 2)?

Either of those would be where I would start looking for different subsequence limits.